# Facebook header navigation bar uses an image instead of simple color

Tags: html, css

I was going through the page source of Facebook and found out that Facebook uses a simple 1X42 (.png) image on the header navigation bar and stretches it to full width, even though they do add a background color too which doesn't take effect because the image is over it.

The rest of the websites such as Twitter, Quora and even Stackoverflow seem to use normal background colors. My question is why would facebook use such a technique to display a color/gradient when the rest of the websites do it the expected way? Does it have some performance benefit or improvement in user experience?

Comment: Likely for optimisation, because the base 64 encoded image is ~395 bytes and CSS for a gradient with equal browser support would be in the realm of 1800 bytes (having just roughly recreated it on [Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/))

Comment: Alright thanks. Actually no one else uses a gradient except Facebook.

Comment: This could be for a multitude of reasons. If indeed Facebook have made this decision for optimisation purposes, it may be such that their particular gradient style was more deserved than other parties, or their budget or requirement for (micro) optimisations was higher. The probable reasons are optimisation and browser support. We can only really speculate. Older IE versions require filters to be used and filters only work when the element is block level or has hasLayout fixes/hacks applied as well as removing ClearType from fonts so perhaps they didn't want those downsides of supporting IE.

Comment: I am new to the web Dev and have only worked on browsers like chorme and Firefox, and have never worked on IE , so had no idea. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using a 1px wide image, then set the background of the respective div to `repeat-x`. This fills the entire screen and makes the gradient the same across all browsers, given the fact certain versions of IE and so on don't support CSS gradients.

Comment: But if that's the case then why have they also set the background color to blue? I mean images can load on every browser right? Or is it so that repeat-x support isn't available on all?

Comment: The colour is likely there so that there's never a time where the bar is missing while the gradient loads.